# How to auto print a wicked pdf in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I want to print my pdf created by wicked, is it possible to print my pdf without pressing `cmd+p`?

I have tried `system("lpr", filename.pdf)`.

Thank you so much for help in advance.

Comment: Does `lpr somepdf.pdf` on the command-line of the server work? Is `filename.pdf` a fully-qualified filename, like `/var/www/rails_app/tmp/filename.pdf`?

Comment: Thank-you for help. even on command line it does not do anything no error nothing done with printing, and yes I have given that files full path.

Comment: I think that system("lpr", filename.pdf) only works on ubuntu not on mac OS and Windows. Any solution for Windows?

Comment: This SuperUser answer may help: https://superuser.com/a/477910/434374 It looks like something like `print /d:COM3 c:\\path\to\filename.pdf` may work on Windows.